# Collection<> objects equal condition is not working wpf c#

Tags: c#

Controls is collection of clsname. To remove setter warnings wee removed set; from the property. So we need to add items one by one to it.

```
public Collection<clsname> Controls
{
    get
    {
        return _controls;
    }
}

Collection<clsName> _controls= new Collection<clsName>();
foreach(UIControl z in _view.Controls)
{
    _controls.Add(z);
}
```

if i assign items one by using .Add() below condition always retuns false. when i check each items from both the object it returns true but as a collection object it fails.

```
if (controls.Controls == _view.Controls)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection<T>` does not override `==` for item-by-item comparison, so you need to check the equality yourself. If the sequence is important, use LINQ's [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
if (controls.Controls.SequenceEqual(_view.Controls)) {
    ...
}
```